# Join inputs, according to the value of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks in advance for your answers. I am making a Javascript function that takes the value of a textarea and reflects it in the inputs. Yes, not one ticket if not several. The purpose of this function is that when you start typing in the text area, the text starts to appear in the first entry. Now, after the text string has spanned the width of the first entry, the text continues into the second entry, and so on. For example, if in the text area I write "Hello my name is Juan Pérez and I live in a country", in the first entry if its width allows to show only "Hello my name is Juan Pérez" the second entry should show "and I live in a country". My code meets this condition if you type the text letter by letter, **but it doesn't work if you paste a text**.

```js
function textarea(id,clas) {
    // body...
    r=[]
    var id_txt= id;
    var clase= clas;
    var b= document.getElementById(id_txt);
    var c= b.value;
    var f=document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[0]
    document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[2].innerHTML=c;
    var g=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[2].offsetWidth;
    var p=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].offsetWidth;
    for(i=0;i<b.value.length;i++){
        tx=""
        tx=c[i]
        console.log(tx)
    }
    if(g>p-5&&g<p+10){
        var t=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].value;
        r=[t.length];
         d= r[0]
        return d
        
    }
    if(g>p-5){
        var t=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].value;
        
        return d
        
    }
    return undefined
}

document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("keyup",function(){
    aa()
})

function aa(){
    h=textarea("app","txt");
    var a=document.getElementById("app").value
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    if(h===undefined){
        p=a.length+1
    }else{
        p=h
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[0].value= a.substring(0,h);
    document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[1].value= a.substring(p);
    console.log(h)
}
```

```css
input{
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
  
  textarea{
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hi</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        input, textarea, div{
            color: white;
        }
        #gg{
            width: max-content;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-3">
            <textarea name="" id="app" cols="30" rows="10" class="bg-dark"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input type="text" class="txt mb-3 bg-dark">
            <input type="text" class="txt bg-dark">
            <div class="txt" id="gg">hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The solution I am looking for is: 1- Make the function work when a user pastes the text. 2- Make this function work on an indefinite number of inputs. Currently it works with two inputs, but how do I make it work with three inputs, each input with different sizes. 3- Make the code more efficient.

Thanks.